Is there anyways to fill the background with gradient color?
I' m trying to draw my winform app with gradient color, however, some accident happened.
I found there exits some areas can not be drawn, just like this picture:
https://i.sstatic.net/MIVxXmpB.png
I've already tried serval ways like change the value of 'height', like this picture:
https://i.sstatic.net/BIlIUGzu.png
Or change the height in the DrawRectangle method, like this picture:
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/pB1zWZOf.png
Is there anyone could come and tell me how to solve this problem?

Are you drawing the gradient manually? Have you seen the Gradient brush ? you probably want to include some example code. Posting screenshots of code is frowned upon.

I'm sorry. I did not know it is unwelcome to post screenshots before. And I do not know "Gradient brush" before. How can I solve this with this tool. I found a example program on Internet, so I want to try by myself based on it.

Screenshots are fine, but screenshots of code cannot utilise search facilities or be copy and pasted by others to test out the issue.  The SO editor allows you to paste code into the question body.

You did not post code and I do not know whether you have tried following:
Override OnSizeChanged and OnPaint:
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ResizeRedraw = true;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var gradientRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);
        // define gradient's properties
        using var b = new LinearGradientBrush(gradientRectangle, Color.White, Color.Black, 45f);
        // apply gradient         
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, gradientRectangle);
    }
}

Here's the result:


ResizeRedraw = true (in the Constructor) -- using (var b = new LinearGradientBrush(...)) <- !important
